# Align (Amsmath): Increase Spacing Between Equation and Number

Tags: equations, amsmath

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &\left(\phi^{\alpha_{t}}\partial_{\tau}+\mathbf{v}_{\parallel}\cdot\phi^{\alpha_{x}}\nabla_{\mathbf{\xi}}+\omega\partial_{z}\right)\omega+\phi\left(2\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{v}\right)_{\bot}+\frac{1}{\phi^3\rho}\partial_{z}p=Q_{\omega}^{\phi}-\frac{1}{\phi^3}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

How can I increase the spacing between equation and equation number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

- Make the equation use less space overall, by (a) replacing the `\left( ... \right)` pairs with `\bigl( ... \bigr)` pairs and (b) "snugging up" some of the subscript symbols -- `\xi` and `\bot` are leading candidates -- to the associated terms. Your original equation is in equation (1) below; the result of the suggested space-saving operations is shown in equation (2). Admittedly not a huge effect, but nothing to sneeeze at either.
- Insert `\quad` or even `\qquad` at the end of the equations to shift the equations to the left; see equations (3) and (4) below. Speaking for myself (who else?!), I don't think there's an advantage in performing either of these left-hand shifts.

The framelines in the following screenshot are there because the solution also loads the `showframe` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' env.
\usepackage{bm}      % for '\bm' ("bold math") macro
\usepackage{showframe} % draw lines around text block

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left(\phi^{\alpha_{t}}\partial_{\tau}+\mathbf{v}_{\parallel}\cdot
\phi^{\alpha_{x}}\nabla_{\mathbf{\xi}}+\omega\partial_{z}\right)\omega
+\phi\left(2\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{v}\right)_{\bot}
+\frac{1}{\phi^3\rho}\partial_{z}p=Q_{\omega}^{\phi}-\frac{1}{\phi^3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bigl(\phi^{\alpha_{t}}\partial_{\tau}+\mathbf{v}_{\parallel}
\cdot\phi^{\alpha_{x}}\nabla_{\!\bm{\xi}}+\omega\partial_{z}\bigr)\omega
+\phi\bigl(2\bm{\Omega}\times\mathbf{v}\bigr)_{\!\bot}
+\frac{1}{\phi^3\rho}\partial_{z}p=Q_{\omega}^{\phi}-\frac{1}{\phi^3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bigl(\phi^{\alpha_{t}}\partial_{\tau}+\mathbf{v}_{\parallel}
\cdot\phi^{\alpha_{x}}\nabla_{\!\bm{\xi}}+\omega\partial_{z}\bigr)\omega
+\phi\bigl(2\bm{\Omega}\times\mathbf{v}\bigr)_{\!\bot}
+\frac{1}{\phi^3\rho}\partial_{z}p=Q_{\omega}^{\phi}-\frac{1}{\phi^3}
\quad
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bigl(\phi^{\alpha_{t}}\partial_{\tau}+\mathbf{v}_{\parallel}
\cdot\phi^{\alpha_{x}}\nabla_{\!\bm{\xi}}+\omega\partial_{z}\bigr)\omega
+\phi\bigl(2\bm{\Omega}\times\mathbf{v}\bigr)_{\!\bot}
+\frac{1}{\phi^3\rho}\partial_{z}p=Q_{\omega}^{\phi}-\frac{1}{\phi^3}
\qquad
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters, don't use `align` for single equation. It's for *alignments*.

Your code produces

[image]

(I added a lipsum paragraph just to show the page boundaries).

According to its rules, TeX is able to center the equation, so it does it, but you can trick it into thinking that the equation is much wider, by adding a lot of horizontal space (that can however be shrinked).

An initial spacing command is needed for the trick to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
\quad
  (\phi^{\alpha_{t}}\partial_{\tau}+\mathbf{v}_{\parallel}\cdot
    \phi^{\alpha_{x}}\nabla_{\xi}+\omega\partial_{z})\omega
  +\phi\left(2\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{v}\right)_{\bot}
  +\frac{1}{\phi^3\rho}\partial_{z}p=Q_{\omega}^{\phi}-\frac{1}{\phi^3}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I removed `\left` and `\right` that do nothing, other than adding unwanted space.

[image]

If you want a boldface `\xi`, load `\usepackage{bm}` and type in `\bm{\xi}`.